# App installs after every build

Tags: xcode

After building my project for running the app installs on to my device every single time.

Preparing to install on to X's iPhone -> Installing on to X's iPhone...

I was also just added to the development team for this project, could it be something with the provisioning profile?

Answer (score 0):

> After building my project for running the app installs on to my device every single time

That's because (1) your destination is the device and (2) the device is connected to the computer. If you don't want to install to the device when you build, then change one or both of those.

Comment: I want to build and run on my device. I just don't need it to install every single time.

Comment: That makes no sense. If you want to build and _not_ run, then build and don't run (Product -> Build). But if you want to build _and_ run, and your app needs building at all, that's because you've changed it. So if you "want to build and run on my device", you _must_ reinstall it. Otherwise you won't be running the version you just built!